# Error: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in value from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable, received org.apache.hadoop.io.Text

Tags: java, hadoop

My MapReduce program is as follows:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;

public class WordCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
        job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
        job.setMapperClass(WordCountMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(WordCountReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(WordCountReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }

    public static class WordCountMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text> {

        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        private Text word = new Text();

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException {
            String[] line = value.toString().split(";");
            int Classe= Integer.parseInt(line[5]);
            String F_Name=line[0];
            int dx= Integer.parseInt(line[1])-Integer.parseInt(line[3]);
            int dy= Integer.parseInt(line[4])-Integer.parseInt(line[2]);;
            int q= (int) sqrt((dx*dx)+(dy*dy));
            String Name_Classe=F_Name+","+Classe;
            String res=1+","+q;
            context.write(new Text(Name_Classe),new Text(res));

        }
    }

    public static class WordCountReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
        private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<String> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int d=0;
            int in=0;
            Iterator<Text> it=context.getValues().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()){

                String value=it.next().toString();
                d = d + Integer.parseInt(value.split(" ")[0]);
                in = in + Integer.parseInt(value.split(" ")[1]);
            }
            String vars2 = context.getCurrentKey().toString();
            String F_Name=vars2.split(" ")[0];
            int An=Integer.parseInt(vars2.split(" ")[1]);
            //std::string result_Key=context.getInputKey();
            String result_value=d+","+An+","+in;
            context.write(new Text(F_Name), new Text(result_value));
        }
    }

}
```

My data looks like:

```
Gr-1;8;8;8;8;0
Gr-1;24;8;24;8;0
Gr-1;40;8;40;8;0
Gr-1;56;8;56;8;0
Gr-2;72;8;72;8;0
Gr-2;88;8;88;8;0
Gr-2;104;8;104;8;0
Gr-2;120;8;120;8;0
```

The error I get is:

```
Error: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in value from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable, received org.apache.hadoop.io.Text


    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1077)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:715)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
        at WordCount$WordCountMapper.map(WordCount.java:46)
        at WordCount$WordCountMapper.map(WordCount.java:32)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the `output value class` as `IntWritable` but your output values from `mapper` and `reducer` are all `Text`. So `hadoop` is expecting `IntWritable` but getting `Text` instead

So please set the following outputValueClass

```
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
```

to

```
job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
```

in your main function

Comment: My pleasure @MEHDISAOUDI. You can upvote my answer as well ;)

Comment: I need 15 reputation to upvote your answer , thanks Ramesh

Comment: You wished and your wish is granted :)